# Excel VBA Remove Duplicates Automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a column from a table and paste it, removing the duplicated cells when doing so. I am using this code:

```
Sub Median()

    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Worksheets("Distance to Default").Activate

With ActiveSheet

    .Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=.Range("T:T")
    .Range("T:T").RemoveDuplicates , Header:=xlNo

End With

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[msgbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddvgC.png)

It would be working properly if it weren't for the fact that a msgbox appears asking me to select for which column I want to remove the duplicates (picture above). Since I am only pasting one column, the question doesn't make sense.

How can I change my code so the box doesn't appear anymore?

Obs.: I have tried to use Columns:=1 just after RemoveDuplicates and it didn't work

Comment: I do not get a box asking me for any input when I use your example

Comment: Is this the full code that you are running? If not, can you post more?

Comment: I posted the complete sub.

Comment: next time it will be *very helpful* to people if you explained clearly that you are using Excel for mac. Will save you from a lot of useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` the msgbox should not appear.

As mentioned in my comment above, I don't get a warning when I use your example, but this code would normally suppress display alerts.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The msgbox still appears tho, and now it gives the option to delete column Q.

Answer (score 0):

### Update:   This will work on a Mac OS

```
Sub MacRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim Data, UniqueData, v
    Dim x As Long

    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    With ActiveSheet

        Data = Intersect(.Range("C:C"), .UsedRange)
        ReDim UniqueData(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To 1)

        For Each v In Data
            If v <> vbNullString Then
                On Error Resume Next
                c.Add vbNullString, v

                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    x = x + 1
                    UniqueData(x, 1) = v
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next

        .Range("T1").Resize(x) = UniqueData
    End With
End Sub
```

### Here are two ways of removing duplicates using Windows OS.

```
Sub Method1()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=.Range("T:T")
        .Range("T:T").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    End With

End Sub


Sub Method2()
    Dim Data, v
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ActiveSheet

        Data = Intersect(.Range("C:C"), .UsedRange)

        For Each v In Data
            If v <> vbNullString Then dict(v) = vbNullString
        Next

        .Range("T1").Resize(dict.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I had tried this one but it didn't work. My code is:

Comment: For the second one, I received an "ActiveX component can't create object" error message

Comment: You received an error on the 2nd because you are using a Mac, which does not have a `Scripting.Dictionary` object.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  Thanks.  I just updated my answer to use a `Collection` instead of a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Add "Columns:=1" to your code. By doing so, automatically the first column of the range is selected:

```
With ActiveSheet

.Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=.Range("T:T")
.Range("T:T").RemoveDuplicates, Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

End With
```

Comment: Maybe this (and the other Solutions) are not working on a Mac. Maybe it is a good idea to use very Basic coding only, without specific vba elements. For example you could Loop through the values, write them in an Array, compare them and delete those values which are mentioned twice. It's a bit more effort but it uses only Loops and Arrays, which are supported by Excel for Mac as far as I know.